# Jprobe Issue with JVM heap memory parameters

Tags: weblogic, permgen, jprobe

When I integrate Jprobe with weblogic and run it by increasing the heap memory I am getting error as "OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space failure".
This is related to jprobe, weblogic server and jvm mainly
Please let me know how can i solve it.

Answer (score 0):

- PremGen is related to JVM hotspot.
- PremGen means Permanent generation. It's space where JVM load classes and jars into memory.
- You can increase size by JVM parameter.

From GC faqs- http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html

- How should the permanent generation be sized?
  The permanent generation is used to hold reflective of the VM itself such as class objects and method objects. These reflective objects are allocated directly into the permanent generation, and it is sized independently from the other generations. Generally, sizing of this generation can be ignored because the default size is adequate. However, programs that load many classes may need a larger permanent generation.
- How can I increase the permanent generation size?
  Use the command line option -XX:MaxPermSize=